# Is $\Bbb Z[x_1,x_2,\Bbb…]/(x_ix_j- {i+j \choose i}x_{i+j})$ a noetherian ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, formal-groups

I computed homomorphism from formal additive group to formal multiplicative group, realizing that it's represented by $R=\Bbb Z[x_1,x_2,\Bbb…]/(x_ix_j- {i+j \choose i}x_{i+j}) $. Here $x_i\ (i \in \Bbb Z_{> 0})$ means free variables.

Intuitively, it's not noetherian. But how to prove it ?

Comment: Well, I do not know what's not intuitive to you... So, basically, in order to be Noetherian it has to have finitely many generators. As $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,...]$ has infinitely many generators, the ideal would have to "take out" all but finitely many of them. As you can't get back $x_i,x_j$ or $x_{I+j}$ from $(x_ix_j - \binom{i+j}{i}x_{i+j})$ ideal won't cut out basically any element....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll abuse notation and also write $x_i$ for the elements of $R$.

If $p$ is prime, $x_p$ is not in the ideal $\langle x_1,\dots,x_{p-1}\rangle$ of $R$ since the binomial coefficient $\binom{p}{k}$ is divisible by $p$ for all $1\leq k\leq p-1$.  Consequently the increasing chain of ideals of $R$
$$
0\subseteq\langle x_1\rangle\subseteq\langle x_1,x_2\rangle\subseteq\dots
$$
has an infinite strictly increasing subchain $\langle x_1,\dots,x_{p_n-1}\rangle$.